# Successive squaring with big exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to calculate $ 2^{5^{77}}\bmod 113 $.
I solved similar problems but with smaller exponent e.g. $ 2^{185}\bmod 113 $ with successive squaring method. Is there any way to use this method to solve it?

Comment: $113$ is prime, so I would reduce $5^{77}$ modulo $112$ first

Comment: @J.W.Tanner why I can do this?

Comment: @JohnOmielan no

Comment: @kekereke Actually, the other question will help give you the answer once you use J.W.Tanner's suggestion, with it being useful since by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) you have $2^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod{113}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks. But what if it wasn't prime number? How can i deal with it?

Comment: @kekereke You're welcome. Note Fermat's little theorem is actually a special case (i.e., for primes only) of [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), which deals with relatively prime numbers modulo $n$, even when $n$ itself is not prime.

Comment: to reduce $5^{77}$ modulo $112$, note that $5^{12}\equiv1\bmod112$

Answer (score 0):

Rather than successive squaring, try successive raising to the $5^{th}$ power:

$2^{5^0}\equiv2\bmod 113$

$2^{5^1}\equiv32\bmod113$

$2^{5^2}\equiv32^5\equiv99\bmod113$

$2^{5^3}\equiv99^5\equiv56\bmod113$

$2^{5^4}\equiv56^5\equiv60\bmod113$

$2^{5^5}\equiv60^5\equiv105\bmod113$

$2^{5^6}\equiv105^5\equiv\color{red}2\bmod113$.

Can you take it from here?   $\;$  Note that $77\equiv5\bmod6$.